# alias in xargs sourcing tcsh

Tags: alias, xargs, tcsh, subshell

I am trying to run an xargs command that uses an alias.  Searching came up with this

```
alias gojk 'stsq \!:1 | xargs -t -0 -I {} tcsh -c  source ~/.tcshrc.user;myset {}'
```

but it returns

```
 Bad ! arg selector
```

and variations will return

```
source: too few arguments.
```

Answer (score 2):

tcsh still evaluates the ! character inside of quotes. You need to put a backslash before it.

I'd suggest you make the tcsh part a script, where you pass it an argument, and get this working. Then call the script using xargs.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-m` flag to `tcsh` to have it read your `~/.tcshrc` on startup, as in

```
... | xargs -t0 -I {} tcsh -m -c "<alias> {}"
```